# When should I use OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime and Instant in database applications?

Tags: java

The documentation of the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package says:

> Many applications can be written only using LocalDate, LocalTime and
> Instant, with the time-zone added at the user interface (UI) layer.

> The offset-based date-time types OffsetTime and OffsetDateTime, are
> intended primarily for use with network protocols and database
> access.

So if I want to save some date-time of an event in a database, e.g. the time a post comment was added to the system, should I use `OffsetDateTime`, not `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant`? Or maybe I should use `LocalDateTime` or `Instant`? Does it depend on the database access technology, e.g. whether I use Hibernate or JDBC?

Are there any rules when to use `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` in database applications?

The summary of the `java.time` package is not clear for me.

Answer (score 27):

My recommendation is to look at what information you need to know beforehand to convert from one type to another or, equivalently, what information you lose.

The concrete use in each case may depend strongly on how the information is used.

However, in general terms:

- `Instant` only store the elapsed time since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z with a precision of nanoseconds. Then, you will be able to convert that instant to the exact date of that instant of time in any time zone, but the time zone is not stored, it is not known, in this class. For example if you need to sort, prioritize, queue, ... times, this could be the right class.
- `Local*` these classes are somewhat the opposite of `Instant`. They store a specific date and time assuming you know (but do not store) what time zone it is. With these classes, you don't know what time instant it is! (unless someone tells you what time zone it occurs in). They can be useful for storing times and dates for which the time zone is known, e.g. arrivals and departures at airports, hotels, ... personal alarms (e.g. wake me up at 8 am every day; no matter where on Earth I am).
- `Offset*` are a bit complicated to understand intuitively. They are like an `Instant` but also store the position on Earth where we are considered to be (not to be confused with "time use"/timezone!). The hours on Earth go from -12h to +12h. `Instant` is in UTC (i.e. +0h), so using `Instant` or `Offset*` is a bit similar, however, these classes are widely used for network protocols, as it is less clear to give an `Instant` 1628340379.718919021 than `2021-08-13T12:24:05.478482150+01:00`.
- `Zoned*` store as much information as possible, because they indicate a "time use"/timezone, that is to say, besides knowing the `Instant`, you know how the user expects you to show that date according to local customs and habits. Many countries on Earth advance or set back the clock according to the time of the year.

There are no silver bullet rules but very generally. If the information you need to store (not to be confused with how you need to display it) is:

- instants in time only to know when something has happened or will happen globally (i.e., no matter where we are on Earth). So `Instant`.
- otherwise, moments in the day, week, month (e.g. every Tuesday) assuming they occur where we are but without specifying where. Then we use `Local*`.
- if we have to transfer an instant of time through a formatted protocol we can use `Instant` but `Offset*` is more appropriate.
- if we have to store also how we will present to the user the time information (hourly usage) then we will use `Zoned*`. But it will be quite rare that we use this class because we are usually interested in the instant when something happens (either globally `Instant` or locally `Local*`) and we will format it to the user according to other preferences.

Only as an example, *postgresql* does not support timezone, then, you must to store or `Local*` or `Instant` (or `Offset*` but **only in UTC** what is bad), in any case you will need to know the hourly usage of the users but, if you have not timezone defined (e.g. you store events) `Instant` will be better.

As I say, without knowing your specific need, it is difficult to say which is better.

Comment: So, I understand that I should use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` to store date-time of the moment you have answered my question, both in Hibernate or in JDBC. But should it be `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: Normally `Offset*` is preferable although `Instant` is perfectly valid (check however the possible limitations of your persistence backend).

Comment: I prefer using instants are they are more human friendly. You can see the relation between 2 dates with the naked eye right away. In case of offse date you have to adjust the calculation in you head when dealing with dates with different offsets. When the offest is the same, it is as easy to read as instants (as instant is in UTC)